# I checked with jconsole and found there is not dead lock,but program does not exit

Tags: java, multithreading, happens-before

```
{static int x;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
            while(true) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },"t2");
        t2.start();
        new Thread(()->{
            sleep(1);
            x = 10;
            t2.interrupt();
        },"t1").start();
        while(!t2.isInterrupted()) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

I verify the happen-before rule,I expect main-Thread and t2-Thread print value of x and exit,but the program is blocked in main thread.I tried to use jconsole to check dead lock and found no dead lock

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to fix it but i am not sure why it's behaving like this, still i am checking. check below code and follow my inline comments

```
{
 static int x;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
            while(true) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                    break;
                }
              System.out.println("t2 completed");// if you add sop here then it's working as expected
            }
        },"t2");
        t2.start();
        new Thread(()->{
            sleep(1);
            x = 10;
            t2.interrupt();
        },"t1").start();
        while(!t2.isInterrupted()) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

i am thinking thread t2 is not returning form the while loop as i called out still checking reason behind this
Thanks

Comment: The reason why this "fixes" the problem is because when you do a print() in Java, changes done in another thread will be visible to all threads. It causes a memory synchronization. However your code is not 100% reliable and the problem is still there. Your code doesn't guarantee success, so maybe go over your solution again.

Documentation:
[Stack Memory and Heap Space](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap)

Comment: @AztecCodes : you mentioned that print() method will cause a memory synchronization and changes done in another thread will be visible to all threads so do you have any documentation for this . https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap this is about stack and heap memory, it didn't mentioned above points.